# How do I filter and remove the indexs from the List that contain only numbers?

Tags: c#, list

```
private void FilterNumbers(List<string> numbers)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    {
       if (numbers[i].Contains
    }
}
```

For example in index 0 i see: "6"
In index 7 i see: "88"

This indexs i want to remove from the List. 
The List is mixed text and numbers index that contain only numbers !! i want to remove those.

My code is not complete. How can I check if the index/s contain only numbers ?

EDIT**

This is what i did:

First i create the original List:

```
private void ExtractText(string filePath)
        {
            List<string> text = new List<string>();
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
            htmlDoc.Load(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));

            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
                var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/b");
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    text.Add(node.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
```

The file is:

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
w.Write(page);
w.Close();
ExtractText(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
```

The problem is that in the end in the ExtractText method the variable text that is a List contain in the first 6 indexs and the last 6 indexs numbers. "0" "6" "8"

What i wanted to do is to extract the text in each between two tags:

Now i want to filter the numbers but its filtering only 3 indexs in the beginning and in the end.

EDIT*

This is where i call the filter method:

```
private void ExtractText(string filePath)
        {
            List<string> text = new List<string>();
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
            htmlDoc.Load(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));

            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
                var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/b");
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    text.Add(node.InnerText);
                }
                FilterNumbers(text);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the [int.TryParse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that checks if the given string can be parsed (converted) to an integer:

```
private List<string> filterNumbers(List<string> mix)
{
    List<string> onlyStrings = new List<string>();
    foreach (var itemToCheck in mix)
    {
        int number = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(itemToCheck, out number))
        {
            onlyStrings.Add(itemToCheck);
        }
    }
    return onlyStrings;
}
```

You can then use the function like this:

```
var mix = new List<string> { "1", "a", "66", "b" };
var strings = filterNumbers(mix);
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

The output is:

```
a
b
```

---

**Update:**

The solution of *Soner Gönül* will also work properly, if the iteration over the list is separated from the removal. This can be achieved using the `ToList` LINQ extension method:

```
private void FilterNumbers(List<string> numbers)
{
    // create a copy of the list, 
    // so that removal does not affect the iteration
    foreach (var item in numbers.ToList())
    {
        if(item.All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            numbers.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The usage ist then as desired:

```
var mix = new List<string> { "1", "5", "bbb", "6", "ABC" };
FilterNumbers(mix);
foreach (var item in mix)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

and the output as expected:

```
bbb
ABC
```

Answer (score 4):

You could filter them with LINQ. Perhaps something like this:

```
private IList<string> FilterNumbers(List<string> numbers) {
    return numbers.Where(x => !x.All(char.IsDigit));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your can use LINQ with [`List<T>.RemoveAt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) like;

```
private void FilterNumbers(List<string> numbers)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
   {
       if(numbers[i].All(Char.IsDigit))
       {
          numbers.Remove(numbers[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Don't forget to add [`System.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace like;

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Soner your code does remove but only 3 indexs in the beginning of the List and 3 indexs of numbers in the End of the List. Maybe i need to make the method recursive ?

Comment: @user3200169 You are right because [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) method renumbered to replace the removed item. From documentation; **When you call RemoveAt to remove an item, the remaining items in the list are renumbered to replace the removed item. For example, if you remove the item at index 3, the item at index 4 is moved to the 3 position.** Update my answer with `Remove` method.

Comment: Even using Remove still removing only 3 indexs at the beginning and 3 in the end . And there are 6 in the beginning and 6 in the end.

Comment: Another option would be to call the `ToList` extension method on the numbers list: `foreach (... numbers.ToList())`. It looks weird, but it creates a copy of the list and the removal of an element from the original list, does not affect the iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a standard way to convert a string to a number using `int.TryParse()` which returns a return value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

```
int num;
if (int.TryParse(numbers[i], out num)) { }
```

This way you can even specify a format of a sequence you want to consider as a number! Check what it offers on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: you are missing `out` in TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Int32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method . as it would let you know wether parsing is successfull or not.

From MSDN: **Int32.TryParse()**

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

Try This:

```
private void FilterNumbers(List<string> numbers)
{
   int number;
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
   {
      if(Int32.TryParse(numbers[i],out number))
      {
         numbers.Remove(numbers[i]);
      }
    }
 }
```